# Proving that a measure is continuous from below

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ be a measure space and $\{E_j\}_{j=1}^\infty \subset \mathcal{M}$ such that $E_1 \subset E_2 \dots $

I want to prove that $\mu(\cup _1^\infty E_j) = \lim_{j \to \infty}\mu(E_j)$. I was wondering if my approach is correct:

**My Approach:** For all $n$ we have $E_n = \cup _1^n E_n$. Therefore, taking $\mu$ on both sides and the limit will give the result.

**Book Approach:** $\mu(\cup _1^\infty E_j) = \Sigma _1^\infty \mu(E_j \setminus E_{j-1}) =  \lim_{j \to \infty}\mu(E_j)$

Comment: Oh, I got the point. My approach is not correct, because limit and $\mu$ do not interchange in general.

Comment: Exact. To prove that a measure is continuous from below is to prove that in this particular situation limit  and $\mu$ are interchangeable. You can not use this fact to prove it.